# Need a Workflow rule for a field unchanged for last 90 Days

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

Flag is a Field on Contact Object.
Trying to Create a workflow rule to create a email if the Flag is checked and unchanged for 90 Days
If the Flag is unchanged for 90 Days then it need to run workflow Task.(Email)

Comment: if flag is false for more then 90 days still you want to send email?

Comment: No. Only when Flag is true for more than 90 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set your workflow rule to "Flag equals true", and add a Time-Based action for "90 days after rule trigger date".

[image: workflow fires after 90 days]

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. It works perfectly. I am trying to send the email to Contact Owner. The Workflow is created on the Child Object. But i couldnt send the email to the contact owner. How can i access it in the email event. is there a place where accessibility is given for emails.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment right now, otherwise I would comment on @sfdcfox answer, but he is correct. When dealing with Time-Based actions in Salesforce if at any time after the rule trigger date (this being the date the field gets checked) the criteria is no longer met (the field getting unchecked) it will fall out and the action will not be performed in 90 days.

Sorry @sfdcfox I wanted to add some clarification to your answer.